# Visual Studio 2010 Web deployment project file error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-deployment-project

I am trying to build a web development project in VS2010, but although all the individual projects build the web deployment project returns the following error.

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(1520,9): error MSB3462: Either MetabasePath or VirtualPath must be specified.

The .Net framework for the main web project is set as .Net 3.5.

Has anyone seen this error before as googling it returns very little.

EDIT: this project was upgraded from VS2008